# Ansible - get list of all of the changed files [after md5 check]

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

My playbook contains this step:

```
- name: copy remotely
  copy_remotely:
  src: "{{ tmp_dir }}/{{ item }}"
  dest: "{{ destination }}/{{item}}"
  with_list: "{{ find_results.stdout.split(\n) }}"
  register: checksum
```

this module is performing remote copy and checks md5/checksum

the register 'checksum' should provide me a list of all of the files
I need to get items which were changed.

when im running this step:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{checksum.results}}"
  when: checksum is changed
```

Im receiving all of the files even if they didn't change, as list of dictionaries
I need to get those which have "'changed': true" state .

is it possible???

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
  - name: Debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{item}}"
    with_items: "{{checksum.results}}"
    when: checksum.changed
```

Comment: Not working, still receiving all of the files even which changed status is false

Comment: Can you share the output? I always test my code and it works

Comment: the output is like
  [
      {
        "name": "file1",
        "id" : "its id",
        changed: "false"
      },
      {
        "name": "file2",
        "id" : "its id",
        changed: "true"
      },
      {
        "name": "file3",
        "id" : "its id",
        changed: "false"
      }
    ]

Comment: Your file2 is changing for some reason. Cah you check if is being copied?

Comment: sure its ok. what i wanted is to get output of the changed file only and dont receive info about files which weren't changed

Comment: You want "when: item.changed" not "when: checksum.changed"

Comment: Oh, and debug: msg="{{ item.item }}"